# Use of comma in reduced adjective/relative clause

Tags: grammar, adjectives, relative-clauses, restrictive-clauses

My **first question** is whether

> **1)** The students who were well-organized passed the exam

==

> **2)** [reduced adjective clause] The students, being well-organized, passed the exam.

If **yes**, my **second question** is whether the commas (i.e. "**, being well-organized  ,**" ) are compulsory in no. **2** (Will it be grammatically wrong if I dont use the commas in no. **2**) ?

I understand that a defining clause is used in no. **1)** and hence no comma there; but I wonder why the commas are required in its  reduced adjective clause construction?

Answer (score 1):

The commas do make a difference. In the first sentence, the relative clause ("who were well-organized") is not surrounded by commas, so it restricts "the students". That implies that not all of the students were well-organized. In the second sentence, the phrase "being well-organized" is surrounded by commas, so it is nonrestrictive. That means that it describes all of the students.

No, you can not remove the commas in the second sentence, because "being" is used merely to describe its referent. For example:

> Correct: My children, being 18 years old, can vote.
> Incorrect: My children being 18 years old can vote.

However, "being" + predicate adjective doesn't need commas if "being" means "acting" or "behaving". For example:

> Some students are being polite today, while others are being rude. The students **being polite** will receive a reward.
> The manager yelled at all of the employees **being irresponsible**.

The difference is somewhat subtle; I suggest you pay close attention whenever you come across one of these "being" constructions.

Comment: @MarclnManhatten " The students being polite will receive a reward." -- this is a similar construction but the commas are not needed since the 'being polite' implying ' acting/behaving polite'; am I right?

Comment: @MarclnManhatten Very nice explanation and informative too. So, in my given example sentences, the 2 has a different meaning than the 1 and hence the adjective clause in the 1 (and in similar implying sentence) should NOT be reduced since the ' ,being well-organized, " in 2 will imply ALL STUDENTS instead of a particular group (i.e., only who were all organized); am I right?

Comment: @Airforce Yes, in fact, you could *add* commas to 1) and alter its meaning. "The students, who were well-organized, passed the exam." —now the meaning is identical to 2).

Comment: @MarclnManhatten Is **your example sentence**, "The students being polite will receive a reward." **reduced** from **1)** "The students who are being polite will receive a reward.", or **2)** "The students who are polite will receive a reward." , or are **both 1) and 2) interchangeable** with your example sentence?

Comment: @Airforce Yes, what Andy Bonner said.

Comment: @Airforce The meaning of those sentences is the same. In both cases, the relative clause is restrictive.

Comment: Summary: A sentence that has a restrictive clause shouldn't be reduced with the 'being' construction, unless the 'being' implies acting/behaving. This is because the reduced clause (with the 'being') requires commas (thus making it a non-restrictive one) and therefore will likely to be different in meaning than its corresponding non-reduced construction. 
Ex 1: "The students who were well-organized passed the exam." **≠** "The students, being well-organized, passed the exam." 
Ex 2: "The students who are polite will receive a reward" **==** "The students being polite will receive a reward."

Comment: @MarclnManhatten it has been tangled because of my too many questions. I am sorry about that. Kindly, see the **Summary** I have written above based on my understanding from your reply.

Comment: @Andy Bonner Thanks.